# Как получить id сообщения из bot.send_message()? aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Отправляю сообщение с помощью bot.send_message() и дальше нужно записать id этого сообщения, только не знаю как его получить.

Answer (score 1):

Если используете `bot.send_message()`, то можете получать `id` сообщения вот так:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types='text')
async def start(message: types.Message):
    msg = await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет!!!')
    print(msg.message_id)
```

но `bot.send_message()` считается устаревшим вариантом, желательно использовать `message.answer()`, например так:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types='text')
async def start(message: types.Message):
    msg = await message.answer('Привет!!!')
    print(msg.message_id)
```

и в первом и во втором случае `id` сообщения, которое вы отправляете будете храниться в `msg.message_id`

Comment: Хотелось бы немного поправить, bot.send_message - никак не устарела, эта конструкция просто служит для немного других целей, нежели message.answer. При помощи первого, например, мы можем сделать массовую рассылку по chat_id, второй же message.answer позволить подобного не может, через костыли мб и то смысл?

Comment: send_message - жив! жил! и будет жить =)

Comment: @1001001, про "устаревший стиль" взято не из головы, а вполне себе из официальной документации (https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/quick_start.html), где прям в базовом примере кода это и помечено как "Old style". Возможно это подразумевает что-то другое?

Comment: "обрабатывать все текстовые сообщения в чате" безусловно message.answer предпочтительней, просто потому что ранее не было message.answer. старый стиль != устаревший. Но повторюсь, для некоторых фич, answer, просто не годиться. copy_message() forward_message() так же служат для определенных целей. Например разница между aiogram2 и aiogram3, я предполагаю что мы не можем сказать, что aiogram2 устарел. С той же доки [FSM](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html) send_message находит себе применение.

Comment: Большинство ботов которых я писал в основе своей отправляли информацию в разные чаты + разным людям(по id). Может я что-то пропустил, но не могу сообразить как без send(forward, copy)_message(photo,video и др.) подобное провернуть. Если появился простой способ, буду рад его изучить.

Comment: Мне нужно было удалять и отправлять сообщения с вспомогательных функций, поэтому использовал bot.send_message(). Только не понимаю, что делает Bot.get_current()? Когда от него пытаюсь сделать что-то, выбивает NoneType

Answer (score -2):

Можете попробовать так:

```
msg = await message.answer('hello world')

print(msg["message_id"]
```

Comment: Этот вариант уже есть в соседнем ответе.